# Защита сайта от воровства информации: как определить робота?

Tags: безопасность, бот, контент

Оптимальная защита - это блокирование парсеров и возможности копирования информации с сайта.

Второе - легко решаемая задача, а вот как можно определить, что на сайт пришел парсер\бот? При заходе на сайт пользователь оставляет некоторую информацию о браузере и свой IP, по этому первым делом можно запретить вход на сайт, если браузер не передал ключи (или как называется то, что браузер передает при подключению к серверу?), но ведь подавляющее кол-во парсеров работает именно через браузер.

Собственно вопрос - как в теории можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: А Вам не кажется, что сама постановка вопроса аморальна?  

Информация должна быть свободной (если уж посетитель может прочесть ее глазами, то и запрещать копировать ее нельзя). Вопрос о честности цитирования, конечно не отменяется.


Comment: Аморальна? Вопрос стоит о блокировании парсеров и ботов - это не правильно. Если пользователь копирует все руками - флаг ему в руки, но использовать "вредоносные" программы - это аморально, а не пытаться от них защититься.

Comment: Если поведение программы аморально (то же и для пользователя), то защищаться (в том числе и активно) правильно. Вопрос в том, является ли копирование информации вредоносным.

Comment: Естественно вредоносно: информация более не воспринимается уникальной поисковыми системами, в поисковых запросах появляется куча левых ссылок, отличных от оригинала, что уменьшает показатели первоисточника. Вреда много и больше ;(

Comment: С осуждением таких действий согласен.

Comment: Попадался сайт с примерами, кажется питона, не помню, интересный сайт, но минус его в отключенном копировании. Представить код примера, ну строк хотя бы 100, кому то захочется вручную набирать его)

Comment: По-моему, аморально воровать чужой труд, а защищаться от воровства - НЕ аморально, это нормально. Причем тут чья-то свобода? Я что, запрещаю кому то говорить в интернете то, что он хочет? Нет, я трачу свое время, пишу статьи, а кто-то их просто крадет, и сует на свой сайт, и в 90% случаев даже ссылки не ставит, а выдает за свое.

Comment: Есть законные способы защиты авторских прав. К чему эти костыли?

Comment: Как только вы придумаете как гарантированно защитить вашу информацию от таких ботов, вы узнаете, что её берут из www.archive.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Парсер ничем не отличается от браузера. Единственно что можно проверить - это скорость перехода по страницам, да и это можно обойти...

собственно ответ - на 100% определить бота никак нельзя.

все суждения строятся на некоторых эвристиках и предположениях.

Comment: Окей. Ведь заходя на сайт я передаю какую либо информацию - так ведь? А парсер\бот? Нет? Хотя, туплю... Ведь парсер запускается через браузер, в основном, и подключается к сайту по тому же протоколу и передает все те же данные...
Неужто действительно спасти свою уникальную информацию никак?

Comment: Ну можно потом искать в гугле свою информацию ....

Comment: Обычно curl и wget не передают информацию об UserAgent.

Comment: Ничто не мешает создателю бота указать любые заголовки такими, каким их выставляют настоящие браузеры и отличить их будет никак нельзя.

Comment: @Сергей curl работает через протокол http\https, так что понять, что подключается к сайту - бот, или "анон" - не возможно. В том то и дело, что парсеры, в основном, работают через curl и в связи с этим отследить их не возможно =(

Comment: Скажем так, про User-Agent рядовые пользователи не знают. А тот, кто хочет стырить информацию, это сделает при любом раскладе. Вон - даже шифрование PDF'ов и eBook'ов не спасает.

Answer (score 2):

Защита информации только от пользователя, если на js сделать можно. Но сам код страницы никак не защитишь. Хотя если какой-то бот пытается слизать вашу страницу, то можно попробовать сначала выдать скелет страницы, и уже потом подгружать контент на ajax, но и о поисковиках можно забыть) ajax пока не индексируется вроде.

Comment: Уже индексируется. Гугл вроде и Яндекс. Краем уха слышал.

Answer (score 2):

Можно текстовую информацию перевести в графический вид. Т.е. отображать как картинку. Плюсы - никто не сможет тупо скопировать текст. А если подшаманить с watermark, то и OCR возможно не поможет. С другой стороны, как пользователь, я просто не стал бы на такой сайт заходить,  т.к. мне важен комфорт. А в случае отображения текста в виде картинки его нет - текст ни скопировать, ни увеличить, да и медленно все отображаться будет. Но эта методика возможна в случае, если необходимо скрыть от поисковиков и запретить прямой копи-паст какой-либо чувствительно информации. Например, моб. телефон продавца на барахолке.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая идея: затемнять экран скриптом, для нечитаемсоти текста, и аякс форму для его закрытия(кнопка закрыть с элементом hidden) если не нажал, перешёл на другую страницу - это бот, отслеживать переход сессией.

Comment: а как насчет отключения JS?)

Comment: Авторы подобных затенителей абсолютно не думают о мобильных пользователях. Заходишь на сайт, а закрыть такое окно не можешь (они его часто центрируют и кнопка недоступна).

Comment: но факт остается фактом, юзеры, у которых отключен JS не смогут попасть на сайт.

Comment: Затемнение можно включать через JS, а для непользующихся просить нажать на кнопочку в < noscript >